# somethings wrong printing picture

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still new to all of this and cant seem to find the problem with this. Heres my main page that everyone sees.

```
 <?php
    // Connects to your Database 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "....", "....") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("....") or die(mysql_error());


    //print animals
    $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10;");
    while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <center><font size=3><font color=#eeb58c><?phpecho $row["Animal Description"]; ?><center>
    <center><font size=1><font color=#eeb58c><?php echo $row["Animal Id"]; ?><center>
    <center><?php 
    $qry = "select ID from animals"; 
    $res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { echo "<img src=inc/image.php?id='$row[0]'>"; }} 
    ?><center>
    <?php
    //close database connection
    @mysql_close();
    ?>
```

here is the image.php page

```
<?php
 // Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("dogs") or die(mysql_error());


$result = mysql_query("SELECT Photo FROM animals WHERE ID= ".$_GET['id']);
if($result === FALSE) 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg", true);
echo $row['Photo'];

?>
```

and here is what I see when I view the source

```
<center><font size=3><font color=#eeb58c><?phpecho $row["Animal Description"]; ?><center>
<center><font size=1><font color=#eeb58c>test<center>
<center><img src=inc/image.php?id='2'><img src=inc/image.php?id='3'><center><font size=3><font color=#eeb58c><?phpecho $row["Animal Description"]; ?><center>
<center><font size=1><font color=#eeb58c>test 2<center>
<center><img src=inc/image.php?id='2'><img src=inc/image.php?id='3'><center>
```

As you see in the source both show image id 2 and 3 what I need it to do is test to show image id 2 and test 2 the show id 3 and so on and so on. Any help would b greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Attention:**  you are using a deprecated application of MySQL. All `mysql` functions are dangerously insecure and open to injection. Please modify your code to use the more secure and go-forward `mysqli`.

Comment: Don't put `@` before your functions to suppress errors and warnings. Make sure you understand which warnings can occur and deal with them appropriately. Aside from the obvious error-hiding (which is always bad) `@` also incurs a hefty performance penalty.

Comment: correct it `$row["Animal_Id"]` instead of `$row["Animal Id"]` and `<?phpecho $row["Animal Description"]; ?>` to `<?php echo $row["Animal_Description"]; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending `2` as id for the photo but `'2'` (with the quotes). That's why you won't get the correct pictures.

Try it this way:

```
echo "<img src=\"inc/image.php?id=$row[0]\">";
```

(And as others already pointed out in the comments, your code is prone for SQL-injections.)

Comment: I have fixed all of the functions and all of the names under the animal table to make it secure and I changed the line to look like you said but it didn't change the way it looked. when I view the source it should look like this <center><font size=3><font color=#eeb58c>test<center>
<center><font size=1><font color=#eeb58c>test<center>
<center><img src="inc/image.php?id=2"><center><font size=3><font color=#eeb58c>500x281<center>
<center><font size=1><font color=#eeb58c>test 2<center>
<center><img src="inc/image.php?id=3"><center>

Comment: but it looks like this. <center><font size=3><font color=#eeb58c>test<center>
<center><font size=1><font color=#eeb58c>test<center>
<center><img src="inc/image.php?id=2"><img src="inc/image.php?id=3"><center><font size=3><font color=#eeb58c>500x281<center>
<center><font size=1><font color=#eeb58c>test 2<center>
<center><img src="inc/image.php?id=2"><img src="inc/image.php?id=3"><center>

Comment: image.php shows a error. Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\dogs\inc\image.php on line 7
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. so I changed it to ID and still the same error but now its ID instead of id

Comment: It is not easy to read your code in your comments here. Please update your question with the steps you took and what's still not working.